# Returning Boolean Value PHP MongoDB

Tags: php, authentication, object, methods, boolean

I am trying to implement error proofing to a log in script.  But, I cannot get it to work?  I have no idea what is going on, or why it doesn't work like I expect it to.  I have tried everything, please advise.

This is the method I am calling:

```
public function i_exist($this_username)
{
    //$host_array = null;
    //$host_array = $this->collection->findOne(array("Username" => $this_username));
    //if ($host_array['Username'] = $this_username)
    //{
          return true;
    //}

    //return false;
}
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
if (!empty($_POST['Username']))
{           
    $host  = new Host();        
    $event = new Event();

    if ($host->i_exist($_POST['Username']))
    {
        header("Location: http://www.drink-social.com/error.php?login=duplicate");  
    }
```

It is supposed to check the database and see if that username is already in use.  But it never directs to the error page?  I have even tried commenting everything out and returning true, and returning 1.  Nothing?
Any advice?

Comment: are you sure the method is called at all? Also you can try calling your page with curl to see/debug the returned headers. (btw, welcome to stackoverflow)

Comment: I am not sure if it is called?  I know everything below is called, because it just seems to skip over that if statement and continue and add the user and assigns them another id?  
It acts like that if statement doesn't exist...?

Comment: Solved.  Because the code below was not wrapped in an else statement, it continued to execute, write to database, and pull up the member's page.
I just assumed when calling header, it stopped executing the code on the previous page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call header(); you will also need to call exit(); otherwise the script continues running.